# задача Шифровка

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код который не принимают, но не подходит:

````
s = input()
k=0
l = ''
d = string.ascii_uppercase
j = string.ascii_lowercase
D=[]
J=[]
for i in range(len(d)):
    D.append(d[i])
    J.append(j[i])
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    z = 0
    while s[i] in D or s[i] in J:
        z+=1
        i+=1
    if z>k:
        k = z
    i+=1
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] in D or s[i] in J:
        if s[i] in D:
            if k + D.index(s[i])>len(D) :
                g = k + D.index(s[i]) - len(D)            
            else:
                g = k + D.index(s[i])
            l += D[g]
        else:
            if k + J.index(s[i])>len(J) :
                g = k + J.index(s[i]) - len(J)            
            else:
                g = k + J.index(s[i])
            l += J[g]         
    else:
        l+=s[i]
print(l)```
````

Comment: а с какого сайта задачка?

Comment: Не выглядит сложным. Нужно найти `k` и после сделать сдвиг по цезарю на k

Answer (score 3):

В этой задаче две цели:

- Определить `k` как количество букв самого длинного слова
- Сделать шифрование Цезарем на значение `k` для букв алфавита

Для определения `k` достаточно строку текста разделить по пробелам, взять от каждого слова его длину и вызвать функцию `max`, так можно будет найти слово с максимальной длиной:

```
text = 'Zb Ra Ca Dab Ra.'
k = max(map(len, text.split()))
# 3
```

Для алгоритма Цезаря взял [свою наработку](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5dd12316dcd024014426c166055896d1e946b6ae/caesar_code/caesar_code.py), она немного избыточная, т.к. поддерживает несколько алфавитов, но это не помешает:

```
import typing

from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
ru_lowercase = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
ru_uppercase = ru_lowercase.upper()

alphabet_list = [
    ascii_lowercase,
    ascii_uppercase,
    ru_lowercase,
    ru_uppercase,

    # Грузинский язык
    'აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტჳუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჴჯჰ',
]


def get_alp_by_char(char: str) -> typing.Optional[list]:
    for alphabet in alphabet_list:
        if char in alphabet:
            return alphabet

    return None


def caesar_code(text: str, shift: int) -> str:
    """Функция принимает текстовую строку и возвращает, новую строку
    символы которой сдвинуты по алфавиту."""

    shift_text = ''

    for c in text:
        alphabet = get_alp_by_char(c)
        if alphabet is None:
            shift_text += c
            continue

        i = (alphabet.index(c) + shift) % len(alphabet)
        shift_text += alphabet[i]

    return shift_text
```

Тестирование:

```
text = 'Zb Ra Ca Dab Ra.'
k = len(max(text.split(), key=len))

new_text = caesar_code(text, k)
print(new_text)
# Ce Ud Fd Gde Ud.
```

Comment: А не проще и понятнее будет `max(map(len, text.split()))`? Использовать два раза `len` выглядит явно избыточным, хотя функция в качестве ключа сортировки - кейс интересный )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ага, так проще будет, спасибо :)