# Обратный шифр цезаря

Tags: c++

Решаю [задачу](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=23830&chapterid=1609#1)
Если просто, то это просто обратный шифр Цезаря, и при этом нам известно, что сдвиг равняется длине самого большого слова в строке.
Написал вот такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    const int len = 250;
    char s[len];
    cin.getline(s, len);
    string s1 = string(s);
    int max = -1, k1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < int(s1.length()); i++) {
        if ((s1[i] == ' ') || (i == int(s1.length()-1))) {
            if (k1 > max)
                max = k1;
            k1 = 0;
        }
        else k1++;
    }

    int k = max;

    for (auto& c : s)
    {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c = ((c - 'a' + k) % 26) + 'a';
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            c = ((c - 'A' + k) % 26) + 'A';
    }

    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Но задача не проходит, подскажите где возможно ошибка

Comment: [Шо, опять?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1269992/281034)

Comment: @ Ага) Я просто к олимпиаде готовлюсь, штудирую задачи, которые преподаватель даёт. Что касается задачи, я понял, что не так. В задаче сказано, что слово это последовательность букв, которые между собой разделены любыми знаками. А моя программа реагирует только на пробелы